# LZW encoding and the GIF file format

Tags: c++, gif, lzw

I'm trying to understand how to create a `.gif` file in C++. So far I think I understand everything except how the `LZW` encoding works. This is the file that I have generated with labels:

```
47 49 46 38 39 61 -header
0A 00 01 00 91 00 -logical screen descriptor
00 00 FF 00 FF 00 -color table [green,red,yellow,black]
00 FF FF 00 00 00
00 21 F9 04 00 00 -graphics control extension
00 00 00 2C 00 00 -image descriptor
00 00 0A 00 01 00 -(10 pixels wide x 1 pixel tall)
00 02 04 8A 05 00 -encoded image
3B                -terminator
```

And here it is again without labels for copy/paste purposes: 47 49 46 38 39 61 05 00 04 00 91 00 00 00 FF 00 FF 00 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00 21 F9 04 00 00 00 00 00 2C 00 00 00 00 0A 00 01 00 00 02 04 8A 05 00 3B

I am having a lot of trouble understanding how `02 04 8A 05` translates to the image `yryryggyry`. I know the `02` is the minimum code size, and the `04` is the length of the image block, and I think I have identified the clear and `EOI` codes, but I don't understand the code inbetween.

```
8A       05
10001010 00000101
100|01010 00000|101
 ^      ????     ^
 clear code      EOI code
```

So far I have gotten the most information from the `.gif` specification:
http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt

And this website was also helpful:
http://www.matthewflickinger.com/lab/whatsinagif/lzw_image_data.asp

Thanks

EDIT*

I watched the Youtube video linked in the comments and encoded the image manually for the color stream "yryryggyry":

```
Color table-012=gry

2   1   2   1   2   0   0   2   1   2
010 001 010 001 010 000 000 010 001 010

current next output dict
010     001  010    21 6
001     010  001    12 7
010     001  -      -
001     010  110    121 8
010     000  010    212 9
000     000  000    00  10
000     010  1010   002 11
010     001  -      -
001     010  110    -
010     -    010    -

outputs-100 010 001 110 010 000 1010 110 010 101

01010101 4th 55
10101000 3rd A8
00101100 2nd 2C
01010100 1st 54

Code-54 2C A8 55
```

I must have made a mistake because this code produces the image "yr" instead of "yryryggyry"

I am going to try to redo the work to see if I get a different answer

Comment: You said you don't understand how the LZW algorithm works, watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2HSd3HCpDs ,hope it will make it clear to you. It's pretty simple, if you got specific question ask them here.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I attempted to follow the encoding process, but I must have done it incorrectly. I have edited the post to show the attempt, maybe someone can find my error

Comment: Why does one section say the image is 5x4 and the other say it's 10x1?

Comment: Thanks, mark. I have corrected the section so that they are both 10x1

Comment: Just so I know I am doing this correctly, can anyone confirm that the string of numbers 01212 encodes to 0127?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you've made a mistake at line 4:
    001     010  110    121 8

At line 3, "010" is ignored, so you have to add it to line 4 first.
And at line 4, it comes to:

```
current  next  output    dict
010 001  010   010 001   212   8
```

Here is my solution(also manually created):

[LZW for yryryggyry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olwhE.jpg)

## Update:

Finally figured out why:

> When you are encoding the data, you increase your code size as soon as your write out the code equal to 2^(current code size)-1. If you are decoding from codes to indexes, you need to increase your code size as soon as you add the code value that is equal to 2^(current code size)-1 to your code table. That is, the next time you grab the next section of bits, you grab one more.

The writer means that you should increase your word size when you are about to output 2^(current code size) - 1, but there might be a different explanation which also seems to be reasonable:

> When you add #(2 ^ current code size) item to the code table, next output should increase its word size.

Also correct in the writer's example, and this is the explanation I prefer.

Here's your example ("yryryggyry"):

```
output sequence:
    #4 #2 #1 #6 #2 #0 #0 #8 #5
```

When you are about to output #6, you add "yry" into your code table, which has an index of #8.

Since 8 = 2 ^ current word size

```
(current word size = 2(original) + 1(reserved) = 3)
```

Next output should increase word size,so #2 becomes a word of 4 bits.

And the final output sequence is:

```
4   100
2   010
1   001
6   110
2   0010
0   0000
0   0000
8   1000
5   0101
```

After encoding they become

```
54 2C 00 58
```

So the data block is

```
02            -minimum word size     
04            -data length
54 2c 00 58   -data
00            -data block terminator
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and for correcting my mistake. This means the new code stream would be 100 010 001 110 010 000 000 1000 101, which turns into 54 2C 00 0B. Unfortunately, while these corrections have increased the compression, they have not really changed the image. For some reason the image is still only two pixels wide.

Comment: Maybe it is because the image size is too small?

Comment: I don't think so. The code 44 54 which decodes to gry works just fine and is only three pixels wide

Comment: I just tried the 23 pixel wide image "01212121212121212121212" which decodes to 44 F4 44 E5 BD 02. It didn't work.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the process now that you've explained it